# Regular Expression Pattern Matching order

Tags: javascript, python, regex

In the Regular Expression engines in all languages I'm familiar with, the `.*` notation indicates matching zero or more characters.  Consider the following Javascript code:

```
var s = "baaabcccb";
var pattern = new RegExp("b.*b");
var match = pattern.exec(s);
if (match) alert(match);
```

This outputs `baaabcccb`

The same thing happens with Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "baaabcccb"
>>> m = re.search("b.*b", s)
>>> m.group(0)
'baaabcccb'
```

What is the reason that both of these languages match `"baaabcccb"` instead of simply `"baaab"`?  The way I read the pattern `b.*b` is "find a sub-string that starts with `b`, then has any number of other characters, then ends with `b`."  Both `baaab` and `baaabcccb` satisfy this requirement, yet both Javascript and Python match the latter.  I would have expected it to match `baaab`, simply because that sub-string satisfies the requirement *and* appears first.

So why does the pattern match `baaabcccb` in this case?  And, is there any way to modify this behavior (in either language) so that it matches `baaab` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the regex not greedy by adding a `?` after the `*` like this: `b.*?b`. Then it will match the smallest string posible. By default the regex is greedy and will try to find the longest possible match.

Comment: might add that it's greedy by default, which means the regex will attempt to match the longest string possible

Answer (score 2):

`.*` is a greedy match. `.*?` is the non-greedy version

Answer (score 2):

Because * and also + are essentially greedy (at least in python, i am not sure about js). They will try to match as far as possible. if you want to avoid this issue you could add ? after them.

Here is a great tutorial about this, in the greedy vs non-greedy section:
[google python class](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/regular-expressions.html)